# Spring Boot JDBC authentication not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-jdbc

I've created a simple JDBC authentication service.

The SecurityConfig:

```
package com.zsl.qrav.backend.BackendApplication;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from users where username=?")
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Here's my database:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+
| user_id | username | password                                                      | enabled | role      |
+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+
|       1 | qrav     | $2y$10$SYZVfjzt/iwXscoTPp5sf.in3fZ8K9OUNWBWP35T5zh9V.aILxpA2  |       1 | ROLE_USER |
+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+
```

The password is simply "password" hashed using:

```
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String pass = "password";
        String encoded = encoder.encode(pass);

        System.out.println(encoded);
```

The problem is, whenever I try to log in with the credentials qrav:password, it just says, that the credentials are incorrect.

There's nothing wrong with the MySQL connection, nor with the database(as it's pretty much a copy paste database from a YouTube tutorial).

I have no idea what's wrong, so I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you hashing the simple text password manually ?

Comment: what version of spring security are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The no-args constructor BCryptPasswordEncoder generates a Bcrypt version 2a based hash but the one stored in your DB is version 2y that's why the issue. You need to check if you have version specified in BCryptPasswordEncoder constructor.

Comment: I've changed my passwordEncoder to
```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder.BCryptVersion.$2Y);
    }
```

But now, while trying to run the program, I get:
```
Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

Comment: can you check your encoded password is v 2y compliant? The one you are comparing with the currently submitted password.

Comment: Your hash looks fine. Try to debug your code and have a look at BCryptPasswodEncoder.matches(...). Maybe its just some quotation marks sneaking in....?

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using version < 5.2** the problem is the generated hash. It should start with `$2a$`. For instance, the following is generated with 10 rounds: password = `$2a$10$7zE9z3rfDEi7WvF.6Sy2Y.UV2MoVTTkX/AzVXEGpjzG3cZ5EsA1YK`

Spring does the following check :

```
private Pattern BCRYPT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\A\\$2a?\\$\\d\\d\\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}");
```

This means the hash has to start with `$2a`, instead yours starts with `$2y`.

Comment: The hash is perfectly fine. 2y is a certain version like 2a and 2b are as well. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html.And newer versions check a range and not only 2a (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java#L38)). So please don't try to answer a question based on old/outdated information.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum thank you for the correction, the link you provided doesn't work. I remember till version 5.1.x this was the case.

Comment: It was added in 2018 in Spring Security 5.2. So it has already been this for 3 years.